# MySQL prepared statement not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch results with this query

```
$lat = -14.4428711;
$long = 28.447634;
$userFk = 11;
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT p.`id`, p.`storeFk`, p.`name`, p.`price`, p.`quantity`, p.`image`, s.`name` ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblpromotion WHERE productFk = p.`id`) 

    as promotional , s.`profilepicture`,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((? - s.latitude)*pi()/180/2),2) +COS(? *pi()/180 )*COS(?*pi()/180) *


    POWER(SIN((?-s.longitude)*pi()/180/2),2))) as distance, p.`dateCreated` FROM `tblproduct` p JOIN `tblstore` s ON p.`storeFk` = s.`id` JOIN tblshoppinglist l ON (


    l.name LIKE concat('%',p.name,'%') AND l.userFk = ?) WHERE s.longitude between (?-100/cos(radians(?))*69) and (? +100/cos(radians(?



    ))*69) and s.latitude between (?-(100/69)) and (? +(100 /69)) GROUP BY p.`id` having distance < 100 ORDER BY distance");


$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss",  $lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $user, $long, $lat, $long, $lat, $lat, $lat);
$stmt->execute();
$response["products"] = array();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $storeFk, $name, $price, $quantity, $itemImage, $shopName, $promotional, $shopProfilePic, $distance, $dateCreated);
 while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
   $product = array();
   $product["id"] = $id;
   $product["storeFk"] = $storeFk;
   $product["itemName"] = $name;
   $product["price"] = $price;
   $product["quantity"] = $quantity;
   $product["itemImage"] = $itemImage;
   $product["shopName"] = $shopName;
   $product["promotional"] = $promotional;
   $product["shopProfilePic"] = $shopProfilePic;
   $product["distance"] = $distance;
   $product["dateCreated"] = $dateCreated;
   $response["products"][] =  $product;

}
```

But not getting anything, When I replace it with values I get results like

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`storeFk`, p.`name`, p.`price`, p.`quantity`, p.`image`, s.`name` ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblpromotion WHERE productFk = p.`id`) as promotional , s.`profilepicture`,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((-14.4428711 - s.latitude)*pi()/180/2),2) +COS(-14.4428711 *pi()/180 )*COS(-14.4428711*pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((28.447634-s.longitude)*pi()/180/2),2))) as distance, p.`dateCreated` FROM `tblproduct` p JOIN `tblstore` s ON p.`storeFk` = s.`id` JOIN tblshoppinglist l ON (l.name LIKE concat('%',p.name,'%') AND l.userFk = 11) WHERE s.longitude between (28.447634-100/cos(radians(-14.4428711))*69) and (28.447634 +100/cos(radians(-14.4428711))*69) and s.latitude between (-14.4428711-(100/69)) and (-14.4428711 +(100 /69)) GROUP BY p.`id` having distance < 100 ORDER BY distance
```

Am new to Php prepared statements, where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you check your SQL query -- Is it returning something in MySQL?

Comment: The second one with absolute values is returning values, but when I rewrite it as a prepared statement its not returning anything.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss",  $lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $userFk, $long, $lat, $long, $lat, $lat, $lat); replace this line

Comment: Let me know if it works!

Comment: Dear Lord, The $userFk was incorrectly typed, write it as an answer I mark it.

Comment: Is this the order $lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $userFk, $long, $lat, $long, $lat, $lat, $lat of the bindparams?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, Replace this line, you have a mistake in code :)

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $userFk, $long, $lat, $long, $lat, $lat, $lat);
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? I can't spot any difference. "Replace this line", why? A good answer will always include an explanation as to what was changed - and why.

Comment: There was a mistake In that line a variable which was undefined he was using

Answer (score 0):

s - for String

d - for double

i - for integer

b - for blob

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss",  $lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $user, $long, $lat, $long, $lat, $lat, $lat);
```